# Mapping object values from one object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash-map

I have an object called `defaultOptions` and a function that accepts as an argument an object called `newValues` meant to override the values in `defaultOptions` with its own.  The values that are not specified in `newValues` should remain default.

```
var configOptions = {
    isActive: false,
    name: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    group: "default"
}

    publishOptions: function(newValues){
      $.each(newValues, function(key, value){
        if(configOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          configOptions[key] = value;
        }
        else{
          configOptions[key] = value;
        }
      });
      console.log(configOptions);
    }
```

For example, if I use this method like so:

```
var myOptions = {
    name: "option one",
    category: "the best"
}

publishOptions(myOptions)
```

I would expect `configOptions` to look like this:

```
configOptions = {
    isActive: false,
    name: "option one",
    description: "",
    category: "the best",
    group: "default"
}
```

I'm using jQuery's `each` method to map the values from `newValues` to `configOptions`, but I suspect there is a much more succinct and elegant way to do this.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can also use ES6 spread syntax like: configOptions = {...configOptions, ...myOptions}

Comment: This may be true, but what's missing is why you would do this.  Is it more efficient?  Easier to read?  Does it handle edge cases better?  Is it more reliable?  What is it about the original code that makes you suggest this alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has `extend`, which seems to be what you are looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Otherwise, if you don't want to use jQuery at all, you can make a for loop:

```
var first  = { value: 1, string: "two" };
var second = { value: 2 };

for ( var i in second )
  if ( first.hasOwnProperty( i ) )
    first[i] = second[i];

first.value == 2; // true
```

---

As a side, your if statement isn't doing anything because both cases assign the value to configOptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lodash's merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) function:

```
var defaultConfigOptions = {
    isActive: false,
    name: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    group: "default"
}

var myOptions = {
    name: "option one",
    category: "the best"
}

var configOptions = _.merge({}, defaultConfigOptions, myOptions)

console.log(configOptions === defaultConfigOptions)
console.log("configOptions: ", configOptions)
console.log("defaultConfigOptions: ", defaultConfigOptions)
```

And this is what you will get:

[image]

See in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jayihus/edit?js,console,output